# How to change the order of fields in field account in the user profile form?

Tags: 7, forms

In the user detail screen (user_profile_form) there is a field: account.

In this field there a different form fields. How to change the order of these form fields? I would like to group the fields current password, new password and confirmation password together.

I did by form_alter ...

```
if($form_id == "user_profile_form") {
   dpm($form) 
}
```

But then? I do not see any key or weight in this array..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're half-way there: just add something like

```
$form['account']['pass']['#weight'] = -6;
```

(event if you don't see the #weight key) and check the results - in this example you should see the current password field go right below password fields.

Comment: Thxs works perfect with value -4 :-)

Comment: It does not work for me. Any idea? Maybe related to https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2476111 ?

Comment: Caches cleared?